# Apache Thrift server logs

Tags: scala, thrift

I have a server which has implemented in scala.

```
import org.apache.thrift.server.TServer
import org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer
import org.apache.thrift.transport.TServerSocket
import org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException
import hms.config.demo.AppStoreConfig

object Server {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    start
  }
  private def start {
    try {
      val serverTransport: TServerSocket = new TServerSocket(7911)
      val processor = new AppStoreConfig.Processor(new AppStoreConfigImpl)
      val server: TServer = new TThreadPoolServer(new TThreadPoolServer.Args(serverTransport).processor(processor))

      println("Starting server on port 7911 ...")

      server.serve
    }
    catch {
      case e: TTransportException => {
        e.printStackTrace
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I need to get logs from the server. That means how it handles the requests and respond to clients like tomcat server. Is there a way to achieve my task in thrift server?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on slf4j as you can see [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.thrift/libthrift/0.9.1) in "depends on". Here is documentation on how to configure slf4j: http://slf4j.org/faq.html. Basically you start by making a config file `src/main/resources/logback.xml` and putting something like this into it:

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>/var/log/mysuperapp/supername.log</file>
        <append>true</append>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

        <logger name="org.apache.thrift.server" level="info" />
        <root level="info">
                <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
        </root>
</configuration>
```

Pick the appropriate level for desired package, add multiple lines for multiple packages. This requires you to have logback dependecy/jar present on classpath.